# Multilinetext in beamercolorbox

Tags: beamer

I'm try to customize a beamer theme with some additional text and logos. I added some pictures already and everything looks fine. Now I want to add a three line text in the head of a presentation. I changed my outer theme and added a `beamercolorbox`. I want to have something like:

```
          some text  ============
    some other text  =   LOGO   =
and again some text  ============
```

I added a `beamercolorbox` with the logo. Now I have some issues with the multiline text. If I do something like:

```
\begin{beamercolortext}[<options>]{<color>}
      line 1 \\
      line 2 \\
      line 3
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

I will just get a text in one line which looks like `line 1 , line 2 , line 3`. If I replace the `\\` by `\newline` then I will get three lines. The problem is that I can't change the spacing. If I do `\vspace{}` then I shift the whole text and the space between the two lines doesn't change.

Is there a better way to add this three lines, maybe something beside beamercolorbox?

**EDIT**

Well. I using the `beamercolorbox` in a definition of an outer theme.

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{split theme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=10.7ex%
  %\@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
  \ifnum\beamer@subsectionmax<\beamer@sectionmax%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \else%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@subsectionmax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 0ex%
    %\advance\@tempdimb by 1.125ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,left]{section in     head/foot}%
      \hspace{1em}\vspace{0.7ex}\pgfuseimage{tu-logo}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,right]{section in   head/foot}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,right]{title}
        test \\
        test \\
        test
      \end{beamercolorbox}
      \vspace{0.7ex}\pgfuseimage{iwm-logo}\hspace{1em}
     \end{beamercolorbox}
  \fi%
}
```

It's close to what is defined in the Warsaw theme. Please don't take the definition of spaces to serious. It's just an example and I wanted to make it work before I define all the spaces. My result for the following code will give me something like -- in the top right corner:[image: problem]

Comment: At my test: \documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[right]{title in head/foot}
    First \    Second \    Third
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
it does work, so maybe can you show a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: While this is still not a MWE, I haven't make any additional tests. But AFAIK beamer redefines \\ at headline. Maybe adding `\raggedleft` after start of `beamercolorbox` would help.

Comment: I added a few things. It's not a real MWE, but I hope it's fine. If I use inside the document the beamercolorbox environment, then everything is fine. The thing just happen inside the definition of the outer theme

Comment: `\raggedleft` have the same effect as `\newline`. It's still without any spacing. Do you know how to add additional spacing?

Comment: There may be many other suggestions, but it would be nice, [if I could test them](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 1):

In places, where multi-line text doesn't work, you could try `\parbox`.

Also here it works with `\\` if you would put the contents into a parbox. Alternatively, you could use `\newline` instead of `\\`. However, if you use `\\` inside the parbox, you could specify optional spacing, such as `\\[2pt]`.

Another approach is using a simple table in that box in the header, with adjusted `\arraystretch` value if desired, such as by

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
```

In all cases, increase the height of the `beamercolorbox`, this means the parameter `ht` in the argument of the `beamercolorbox` environment.